# Memory leak in weakValue map reference for synchronized method

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, synchronization, concurrent-collections

I am creating an interface for executing methods concurrently, while abstracting away the synchronization details (To swap for a distributed implementation when needed). I've created a single jvm implementation that allows Strings to be used as the mutex by storing them in a map to ensure one reference is used, even if Strings of different references are passed in. The concurrency seems to work fine, however I was surprised to see that the test was showing the reference count is never decreasing. I assumed using WeakValues() would be enough to prevent memory leaks, but it seems that is not the case. Can anyone point out what could be causing this leak?

```
public class SynchronousMethodExecutorSynchronizedImpl implements ISynchronousMethodExecutor {

// mutex map to provide string references
final Map<String, String> mutexMap = new MapMaker()
    .weakValues()
    .makeComputingMap(
        new Function<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String id) {
            return id;
        }
    });

@Override
public Object doSynchronousMethod(String domain, String id, ISynchronousMethod synchronousMethod) {
    synchronized(mutexMap.get(domain + "." + id))
    {
        return synchronousMethod.execute();
    } 
}
```

}

Here is the test that is failing at the very last assertion:

```
public class SynchronousMethodExecutorSynchronizedImplTest extends TestCase {
int counter;
SynchronousMethodExecutorSynchronizedImpl methodExecutor;

@Override
public void before() throws Exception {
    super.before();

    methodExecutor = new SynchronousMethodExecutorSynchronizedImpl();
}

@Test
public void concurrentExecute() throws InterruptedException {
    assertEquals(0, counter);

    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        getConcurrentExecutorThread().start();

    // wait for threads to complete
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    assertEquals(1, methodExecutor.mutexMap.size());

    try
    { 
        final List<long[]> infiniteList = new LinkedList<long[]>(); 

       for(long i = Long.MIN_VALUE; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++)
            infiniteList.add(new long[102400]); 

        fail("An OutOfMemoryError should be thrown");
    } 
    catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
    { 

    }

    assertEquals(2000, counter);
    assertEquals(0, methodExecutor.mutexMap.size());
}

// synchronous method
private ISynchronousMethod method = new ISynchronousMethod() {
    @Override
    public Object execute() {
        counter++;  
        return null;
    }
};

/**
 * Executes a line of code.
 * 
 * @return Thread
 */
private Thread getConcurrentExecutorThread() {
    return new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            methodExecutor.doSynchronousMethod("TEST", "1", method);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {

            }
            methodExecutor.doSynchronousMethod("TEST", new String("1"), method);        
        }

    };
}
```

}

This last assertion is what breaks the test:
assertEquals(0, methodExecutor.mutexMap.size());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're storing the exact same `String` object as both the key and the value. The key is a strong reference to the object, and as long as a strong reference to it exists, the weak reference to it is meaningless. The definition of *weakly reachable* ([here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability)) states that:

> An object is weakly reachable if it is neither strongly nor softly reachable but can be reached by traversing a weak reference.

By the way, even with this corrected I don't think you can assume that the map will always be empty at the end. It will probably be close to empty, but I think that's all that can be said about it.

Comment: Very good sir! I changed it to store a new String(id), and it works like a charm!

Comment: Why do you say that the map won't always be empty?

Comment: @Anthony: I could be wrong, but I don't think there's any guarantee about when exactly the weak references will be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Weak references will only be collected when the JVM absolutely needs more memory.

Comment: But in my test I am explicitly failing if an OutOfMemoryError does not occur, but that assertion does not break. I put the last assertion which runs after the OOM occurs, and I expect there the values to be removed but they are not.

Comment: The OutOfMemoryError is occurring because you are storing a list of strong references.  That is, your infiniteList is a strong reference and contains strong references to arrays of longs.

Comment: Soft references are collected when the JVM needs more memory. Weak references may be collected even if it doesn't.